# PLSQL Execute another Select statement if First is Empty with ref cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to do something similar to the following:

```
procedure some_name ( p_ref_cursor in out nocopy sys_refcursor )

is

begin

open p_ref_cursor for
select item1, item2 from (some complicated join query);

fetch p_ref_cursor into xx;
if p_ref_cursor%NOTFOUND
then
select item1, item2 from table2 where item3='y';
end if;

end
```

If the first select statement returns nothing it should execute the second select statement to retrieve values. The problem I am running into is when the cursor is fetched, the result set is cleared out. So regardless if the first select statement found anything, it acts as if it was not found.

I have tried the following:

```
procedure some_name ( p_ref_cursor in out nocopy sys_refcursor )

is
local_var1 number
local_var2 number
begin

open p_ref_cursor for
select item1, item2 
into local_var1, local_var2
from (some complicated join query);

if local_var1 is null
then
select item1, item2 from table2 where item3='y';
end if;

end
```

However it looks like the INTO statement does not work with ref cursor.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Is this a direct copy?  info vs into?

Comment: yes that's a typo. It's into

Comment: What I ended up doing was to return two ref cursors. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like overkill for something that I think should work.  But I believe it would work around the problem and eliminate the need for your if statements.  Additionally it may be slightly slower since it has to do both queries.  So if performance is of the utmost concern, then I wouldn't use this.

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT item1, item2, '1' as Src 
FROM (some complicated join query)
UNION
SELECT item1, item2, '2' as SRC
FROM table2 where item3='y')
SELECT item1, item2
FROM CTE
WHERE src = (Select min(src) from cte)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Performance is a concern so I do not want to do a union :(

Comment: Try using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. `UNION` eliminates duplicates in the result set, which can be very time consuming; `UNION ALL` dispenses with the duplicate checking, and often provides much better performance. Share and enjoy.